# Set p_sign_posn in LC_MONETARY

Tags: python

I need set property in `LC_MONETARY` in locale `pt_BR`.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')
'pt_BR'
>>> value = 1234567.89
>>> locale.currency(value)
'1234567,89 R$'
```

but normal format of currency is `R$ 1.234.567,89`.

I see the doc in https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.LC_MONETARY but not have methods to set `p_sign_posn` property?

Comment: does `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')` make a difference?

Comment: No. Is the same return.

Comment: Version is `3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`

Comment: It is definitely an os issue, the code runs fine for me on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is given in the locale data for the operating system. If you feel that the value is incorrect then you should file a bug with the developer of your OS.